# Number of stall cycles when there is only EX/MEM pipeline registers or only MEM/WB pipeline register

Tags: assembly, architecture, mips, cpu-architecture, pipelining

I am working on a problem which is related to The processor. The problem is the problem 4.12 in the book whose title is "Computer Organization and Design (6th Edition)". The problem has the assumption as following:
[image]
Here is an image Figure 4.45
[image]

And the question number 3 makes me stuck on it
[image]

The answer for this problem is MEM/WB has fewer number of stall cycles (which has CPI is 1.35) than EX/MEM (which has CPI is 1.45). I am quite confused with the explanation of this answer.
It states that:

> With forwarding only from the EX/MEM register, EX to 1st dependences
> can be satisfied without stalls but any other dependences (even when
> together with EX to 1st) incur a one-cycle stall. With forwarding only from
> the MEM/WB register, EX to 2nd dependences incur no stalls. MEM to 1st
> dependences still incur a one-cycle stall, and EX to 1st dependences now
> incur one stall cycle because we must wait for the instruction to complete
> the MEM stage to be able to forward to the next instruction

It is correct that with only EX/MEM pipeline register, EX to 1st is solved, however, I can not prove the all of the other cases needs ONLY ONE STALL CYCLE. For example, in the case of MEM to 1st, I think it need for 2 stall cycles because the result now is produced at MEM stage, which does not has any MEM/WB pipeline register to save the result and forward it to the next instruction. Therefore, with 2 more stall cycles, it will have the correct result. And one more thing that I want to tell you is in the case of "EX to 1st and MEM to 2nd", in the answer, it also requires one more cycle to solve hazards here. It makes me so confused because it conflicts with the case "MEM to 1st" which required only 1 cycle too.

Similarly in the next case of only MEM/WB pipe line register. Do you have any proofs for the explanation of this answer? I really look forward to your answers of this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not about having the pipeline register (or not, without the pipeline register it won't work at all), but rather having the bypass/forward muxing that provides data to mitigate the RAW hazard vs. causing a stall instead (which would be silly since the logic to detect the condition must be implemented in both cases or else the processor wont work).

You are right in thinking that MEM to 1st requires 2 stall cycles if there is no bypass/forward, and with a bypass/forward, only one cycle of the 2 is mitigated, the other stall cycle is still there and cannot be removed via bypass/forward.  Why?  Because the data needed is simply not available anywhere in the processor for the 1st after until one cycle later than needed for the 1st after's EX.

In the other cases of bypass/forward, the data is available somewhere in the processor at the right time to proceed with 1st or 2nd after — just that the data is not in the right place, so the bypass/forward fixes that.  For example, in the cycle after an `add` instruction finishes its EX, the value of the arithmetic addition operation is somewhere in the processor but not yet in the target register.  An instruction 1st after that uses that target (for another addition, say) naturally goes into the EX stage one cycle after, and thus the proper data is available timing-wise but is simply not in the right place (which would be the prior's target register), so a bypass realizes the RAW hazard and chooses the prior EX output instead of the stale value from the 1st after's ID-stage register read.

Whereas with a MEM to 1st RAW, the data won't be available anywhere in the processor until 1 cycle after the 1st after's EX stage, so one stall plus a bypass is used, and is the best that can be done.

What they are asking about is the cost of a three-way mux that can choose between bypass/forward from EX, bypass/forward from MEM, vs. a non-forward/register read from ID, in the same clock cycle.

If you want to support any of the above three items, a three-way mux (or two levels of two-way muxes) are necessary.  Remove any one of the items and you can reduce muxing.

---

You can search for load/use RAW hazards for more detail.

In essence, let's say that a load instruction that enters `IF` at time `t`, is thus in `ID` at `t+1`, in `EX` at `t+2`, in `MEM` at `t+3` and `WB` at `t+4`, five cycles in all.

If that load (say `lw $a0, 0($a1)` is immediately followed by an instruction that uses the load's target register (say `addi $t0, $a0, 1`), then that instruction (the `addi`) enters the pipeline, `IF`, at time `t+1`, and it goes into `ID` at `t+2`, and `EX` at `t+3`.  At the beginning of cycle `t+3` the data required for the `addi` to execute — the increment using the ALU in `EX` — is no where in the processor, and it won't arrive in the processor until the end of `t+3`, which is the end of the load's MEM cycle.  So, even with a bypass/forward, a stall cycle is unavoidable and required.  In this scenario, the stall delays the `addi`s `EX` stage until `t+4`, a time when the data is available somewhere in the processor.  At `t+4` the load's data could be re-taken from the architectural register file (though that would require triple porting the read side of the register file, and would also probably increase the cycle time to accommodate that), or, be obtained from the MEM/WB pipeline register).

Since the architectural register file is read to obtain source operand values in the `ID` stage, without a bypass/forward, two stalls are required to delay the `addi`s `ID` (which ideally would have happened at `t+1`) until `t+4` when it can see results of the load's `WB` stage in the architectural register file.

Comment: I think it is not true because "MEM to 1st" means that the result is available only after the MEM stage is finished (For example, the ``load`` instruction). In order to forward this result, there should be a MEM/WB register for the next instruction, right? However, in this case, there is no MEM/WB register as an assumption. So there should be NO FORWARD/BYPASS and it returns to the normal case with no FORWARD/BYPASS with 2 more stall cycles

Comment: MIPS pipelining spreads out the execution of a single instruction into 5 stages, each taking one cycle.  The processor sources operands from the register file (not pipeline registers) in the ID-stage of any given instruction.  The processor can choose to take values from the pipeline registers (essentially overriding values obtained in the instruction's earlier ID stage), and it should do this when there is a hazard, as in the hazard cases, the ID-stage register-file read operations have returned stale values.

Comment: There has to be a MEM/WB pipeline register regardless of hazards.  It is necessary to get the values from MEM stage written into the target register in the WB stage.  It is necessary to have MEM/WB pipeline register even for non-load (e.g. R-Type) instructions.  (In the case of R-Type instructions, the MEM/WB pipeline register simply holds a copy of the EX/MEM pipeline register but one cycle delayed, and unaltered by the MEM stage.)  Only the WB stage can write to the register file, and each instruction gets one cycle in WB stage, so it can write its results to the architectural register file.

Comment: The pipeline registers between stages are a pipeline implementation detail that are wholly separate from the architecturally defined register file (the 32 registers).  The purpose of the pipeline registers is to capture results from one stage at the end of a clock cycle and provide those results to the next stage at the beginning of the next clock cycle.  Thus, these pipeline registers move an instruction from stage to stage.  They are necessary independent of bypass/forwarding.

Comment: When a hazard exists, mitigation can be done as bypass/forward, sourcing an operand (that has been computed but hasn't yet been written to the proper target register of the architectural register file) directly from some pipeline register, if some pipeline register has the proper architectural value (a value needed as per some code sequence).  When no pipeline register actually has the architecturally required value, a stall must occur to wait for it.  Such is the case for a RAW hazard involving MEM in one instruction (a load) and EX in the 1st instruction after using that target register.

Comment: I still don't get it and I am sorry for it. I know the theory of pipeline register which will be forwarded as hazard is detected. However, as I have mentioned, if there is only one cycle for the case MEM to 1st, the MEM stage of the initial instruction will be collided with the ID stage of the next instruction. But there is no MEM/WB as an assumption which means THERE IS NO FORWARD HERE. Can you add to your answer with an example with a simple case (such as the first instruction is ``load $1, 0($2)`` and the second instruction is ``add $3, $5, $1``) which corresponds to the case MEM to 1st?

Comment: ***There must be a MEM/WB pipeline register, full stop.***  Without pipeline stage registers, the processor cannot have stages, so could not be pipelined.  So, you should not say there is no MEM/WB.   Though *forwarding from MEM/WB pipeline register to an earlier stage* to mitigate hazards is optional as stalls work as well in hazard mitigation (though they are silly when a bypass would work, since the hazard detection must be done regardless of bypass).

Comment: I have added a brief explanation of load-use RAW hazard.

Comment: You say that "So, even with a bypass/forward, a stall cycle is unavoidable and required". However, at the time t+3, even when you added one more cycle, at the end of the MEM stage (t + 3), the value has not been written back to the destination register (because it has not executed WB stage yet). So is it OK here? And one more thing that I want to tell you is in the case of "EX to 1st and MEM to 2nd", in the answer, it also requires one more cycle to solve hazards here. It makes me so confused because it conflicts with the case "MEM to 1st" which required only 1 cycle too, can you explain this?

Comment: In the load/use RAW hazard scenario I described, the data is not available until the very end of `t+3`, which is the same time instant as the very beginning of `t+4`.  So, it cannot be effectively used by an `EX` cycle until `t+4`, since `EX` (the ALU) needs the data at the beginning of the cycle.

Comment: In the case that a value could " be obtained from the MEM/WB pipeline register" you mentioned in the answer, does it violate the assumption in the problem ("ONLY from the EX/MEM pipeline register or ONLY from the MEM/WB pipeline register")?

Comment: Yes, obtaining a bypass value from the MEM/WB pipeline register, if disallowed, is not permitted.  However, if that is disallowed, then there is only one practical approach left, which is to stall the ID stage until it can read the proper value, and that means 2 stall cycles for a load/use RAW hazard.

Comment: Yes, that's the thing that makes me confused here. That's why I think that there should be 2 cycles instead of 1 cycle to solve this hazard. However, I think that there can be another "trick" here to explain this

Comment: Without bypass/forward, 2 stall cycles are needed to cover this hazard: these stalls wait for the (load instruction's) data to reach the register file so it can be read out from there; without a bypass, such an instruction (following a load and using also its target) must stay in ID until the load's WB stage.

Comment: If a bypass can be used, then one of the 2 cycles of the load-use RAW hazard can be eliminated: taking data from MEM/WB pipeline registers (mem stage output) toward EX/ALU input overriding the ID-read value (which saves the load's WB cycle), but then a 1 cycle stall is still required to cover the other hazard cycle: that stall waits for MEM to complete so the value can be given to EX.  Bypass + 1 stall cycle for load-use hazard is as good as we can do.